# Remove default value in SQLDataSource

Tags: c#, .net

I am using an SQLDataSource which holds a parameter value I wish to select when a page is loaded. This parameter has a default value, but in PostBack I would like this default value to be deleted. However, I don't know how to remove the default value in an SQLDataSource. I want to do try something like this:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB_ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="mqa.S_test_Conference_Select_Date" 
        SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" onload="SqlDataSource2_Load">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" DefaultValue="null" 
                Name="ConferenceID" PropertyName="Text" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1"  Name="ConferenceName" 
                PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["ConferenceName"].DefaultValue = null;
SqlDataSource2.SelectParameters["ConferenceName"].ConvertEmptyStringToNull = true;
```

Comment: Use Web.Config file and/or you should handle page_load please tell more about your problem

Comment: I have some textboxes which are used to enter search values. I have a stored procedure that has 2 datetimes, 1 int and 1 char parameter. I attach my SqlDataSource to a TextBox and set the default value to null but when I run my project empty is passed to the stored procedure but my stored procedure expects a null value.when parameter has string type i have no problem but when i add dateTime and int parameter i have no result

Comment: As i understood you have a datasource which is bound to a sql database and a select command which call a storedprocedure with a parameter and  i think you pass wrong value to parameter or may be your storedprocedure should handle two or more parameters.

Comment: May i have a look at storedprocedure and/or you page_load code behind?

Comment: yes i bind it and wrong value pass to stored procedure.my sp is ok but my problem is passing value.

Comment: did you bind textbox value as parameter

Comment: In code behind you can set a default value to parameter following link  can provide you a good example.
http://csharp-station.com/Tutorials/AdoDotNet/Lesson07.aspx